# Collaborative pricing tool

Tags: web-apps, collaboration

I'm looking for a web-based collaborative solution for managing the pricing (sales and purchases) of many product references. I couldn't find any existing solution matching my company's needs as they actually consist in a three tiers relationship between products, markets, and suppliers.

- a same product may have several suppliers who define a different purchase price
- a same product may be sold to different markets (countries) with specific currency, price and discount
- when a product has several suppliers, these are manually sorted. This allows the selection of the best supplier within the order creation process

Has anyone worked with this kind of tool already ?

Answer (score 4):

The company I work for has a product which can do about 70% of what you need. If you can afford to shelf over money for this, I suggest to contact them. I’ve asked a coworker who knows about it, and he told me to relay the following information (I’ve omitted a few details):

[RUPIO](http://www.esolutions.ro/rupio?languageId=en_US) is a web application which supports pricing managers in their task to set prices and implement pricing strategies. Here is [a (German-language) page with more infos and contact points](https://www.tarent.de/produkte/automated-pricing), and [this is an English one-pager (PDF)](http://www.esolutions.ro/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=c7ef1ff5-1d79-4ea8-9c74-7666e59a923b&groupId=10136). You can contact either the Romanian or German office in English.

You can combine it with COPIO – [English one-pager](https://he.tarent.de/nhaeri/copio-Onepager-en.pdf), and the [(German language) website](https://www.tarent.de/produkte/competitor-analysis).

### Operational tool

- Matches your internal structure (Category hierachy / regions)
- Supports multiple pricing policies & strategies (Cost plus pricing, Price Flooring, competition based pricing);
- Hierarchical pricing rules aproach, for easy maintennance of the rules;
- Uses market seggregation (multiple meta attributes)
- Rule based pricing - uses state of the art, advanced rules engine; Rules are admninistrable at multiple levels, using UI
- Role based activities (admin  / supervisor / category manager) that accomodates your existing organizational infrastructure
- Advanced Security and Permission management
- Multi attribute, multi dimensional pricing -
- Powerfull filters to narrow down pricing execution
- Massive computing calculations (e.g. gracefully supports over 100 000  products in a multi store environment - over 100 stores)
- Adjustable workflows
- Automatic / schedulable actions
- Multiple price validation rules (threshold and rules based)
- Overwritable decisions (manual overwrite of prices on a easy to use interface)
- Powerfull, feature rich easy to use UI
- Web interface
- Export  /import from Excell
- Supports product bundling pricing
- Integrates with promotion management tools
- Promotion management capabilities

### Analytical tool

- Embeds and integrates reporting and BI capabilities
- Offers in app charts and hystorical information to assist a better pricing decision

### Predictive analysis

- estimate the impact of price changes

### Price execution and management

- Operations are audited
- Automatic publishing tool (JMS / ESB / direct database access, flat files, etc)
- Export of prices
- Schedulable actions